# Firebase PendingDynamicLinkData is sometimes null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to implement Firebase dynamic links in my app.
I'm using custom domain of mine (instead of the one provided by firebase).
It works most of the time.

However, on a specific device (Samsung A7), the dynamic link is sometimes null

Here's the standard code for pulling the dynamic link:

```
   FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(intent).addOnSuccessListener { dynamicData ->

        val link = dynamicData?.link

        if (link != null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "pullDynamicLinkAsync", "dynamic link found")
        }

    }.addOnFailureListener {

        Log.i(TAG, "pullDynamicLinkAsync", "dynamic link not found")
    }
```

The steps of my test:

- Click on the shared dynamic link -> Play store page of my app (previous version) gets opened
- Make a fresh install of the app from Android Studio
- Call the above code directly from onCreate method

As I said, most of the time it works and I get the link.

Could it be an issue related to the specific device? Maybe Play services issue? Or limitation?

**EDIT (03/12/2020):**

It seems like this issue is somehow related to **Chrome** browser.

When I press the dynamic link and the browser (in this case - chrome), opens, The following line gets printed in the log **most of the time**:

```
**I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.VIEW_DYNAMIC_LINK ...**
```

- If the line appears in the log, I always received the dynamic link in my app
- If the lines doesn't appear in the log, I never receive the dynamic link in my app

The issue happens only with chrome browser.
If I open the link with other browser (Firefox, build in browser..) it always works.